# Year fractions using Actual/365 convention in R

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

Is there any function/package that can compute  year fraction (differences between two dates)  with different day-counting convention, like **yearfrac()** in Matlab? I need to use Actual/365 convention.

Comment: `Rquantlib` has many day counters `Actual360`,`Actual365`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rollYourOwn <- function(D, origin=as.Date("1970-01-01")) {
  if (!inherits(D, "Date"))
    D <- as.Date(D, origin=origin)
  as.numeric(D - as.Date(format(D, "%Y-01-01"), origin=origin) + 1) / 365
}

rollYourOwn("2014-01-01")
# [1] 0.00273973

rollYourOwn(Sys.Date())
# [1] 0.742466

rollYourOwn("2014-12-31")
# [1] 1
```

Comment: What's the desired behaviour for leap years?  For example, `rollYourOwn("2012-12-31")` is greater than one.  Is that right?

Comment: @RichieCotton it depends on the market.  This is an implementation of Actual/365 Fixed.  Actual/365 would treat leap years differently.  see http://support.treasuryview.com/kb/treasury/day-count-convention... edit: there's probably a more reliable source out there, I just picked the first thing I saw in google